# Hive- Workaround for checking sub partition

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive

I have an Oracle table **Tab_O** and its equivalent table in Hive **Tab_H**. Both tables are partitioned based on column **Part_Col**.

```
Tab_O/ Tab_H
+---+---+---+----------+-----+
| A | B | C | Part_Col | Bal |
+---+---+---+----------+-----+
| 2 | 1 | 9 |   2005   | 100 |
+---+---+---+----------+-----+
| 3 | 1 | 9 |   2005   | 400 |
+---+---+---+----------+-----+
| 3 | 2 | 8 |   2005   | 300 |
+---+---+---+----------+-----+
| 4 | 1 | 9 |   2005   | 200 |
+---+---+---+----------+-----+
```

The Oracle table has subpartitions on columns B and C, eg. `B1_C9`, which can be checked from `ALL_TABS_SUBPARTITIONS`. I perform different operations based on whether or not the subpartition exists.

But I cannot check for subpartitions in Hive. So would just checking if the data exists be a sufficient workaround?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TAB_H WHERE B=1 AND C=9;
```

Or could this cause some other problem?

Comment: I don't know Hive, but as I found there is a "SHOW PARTITIONS table_name;" command there. Isn't it an option?

Comment: @Galcoholic that option would just list the partitions and not the sub partitions. Sub partitioning don't exist in Hive as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If statistics is not available or may be not available or may be stale for (sub)partitions then better and safer to use `LIMIT 1` for checking data rather than count because in such case `count(*)` may cause full (sub)partition scan.  In case you are using statistics for `count(*)` (`set hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;`) and statistics is stale then you will receive wrong result.

This should run without starting map-reduce, as a fetch-only task:

```
SELECT 1 FROM TAB_H WHERE B=1 AND C=9 limit 1;
```

You can wrap above command in a shell script, analyze result.

Also you can check folders exist.
Hive partitions are hierarchical folder structure. You can use shell script with `hadoop fs` for checking folder exists and pass the result to Hive scripts if necessary using `hiveconf` or `hivevar` variables or conditionally execute your Hive scripts from the shell. Shell command example:

if $(hadoop fs -test -d $your_sub_partition_dir) ; then echo "exists";else echo "not exists"; fi

**Note that partition folder may be empty, partition exists but does not contain any data. This is quite possible if data files were deleted without dropping partition.** So the first approach may be preferable.